# Pass data to two view controllers in the two tabbars

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a login page that get a username from user
this login page is connected to a `UITabbarController` which contain for tabs (viewControllers). 
After tapping on login button, I pass the username to the first view in tabs through `prepare segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profile" { 
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navProfile = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        if let profile = navProfile.viewControllers[0] as? ProfilePage {
            profile.username = self.usernameInput.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this username should also pass to the second tabs. I tried to it in the `prepare segue` along the first tab

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profile" { 
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navProfile = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        if let profile = navProfile.viewControllers[0] as? ProfilePage {
            profile.username = self.usernameInput.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        }
        let navTimeline = barViewControllers.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
        if let timeline = navTimeline.viewControllers[1] as? TimelinePage {
            timeline.username = self.usernameInput.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        }
    }
}
```

But the app is crashed with this error

```
index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

could anyone help me how to pass username to the second tab as well?

Comment: Don't try to manipulate the tab bar's other view controllers from here. Hand the data to the `profile` view controller as you are doing, and let _it_ hand the data on in its `viewDidLoad` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 if let timeline = navTimeline.viewControllers[1] as? TimelinePage {
```

with

```
 if let timeline = navTimeline.viewControllers.first as? TimelinePage {
```

As the navigation has only 1 vc so index 1 will crash

---

Also it's better to have a singleton class of your user model shared all over the app

Comment: @Sh-Khan Thank you so much, Actually, I used userdefaults to keep the username and use it everywhere, but I don't know why when the user logout the app and enter the username again, the new value is not replaced by old value in userdefaults. I have to close the app and open it again to see the new value in userdefaults.

Comment: you may need to refresh the ui after the logout also track your  user default value with prints/breakpoints